# Setting up UK VAT for European Union countrires

Tags: expresso-store

For UK Value Added Tax, we need to charge 20% on goods shipped to countries in the EU, 0% on others. TO achieve that it looks like I need to add a rule for each EU country, rather than one rule for multiple countries.

Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to add a tax rule for each country that you need to apply the 20% tax to.